# Can't access matplotlib title fontsize when not centered

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Not sure what's going on here.  If I set `loc='left'` or `loc='right'` the `get_fontsize` method no longer points to the non-centered title.

How do I access the fontsize of a left aligned title?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set up a blank plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Set title with fontsize of 30 
ax.set_title('test_title', loc='left', fontsize=30)

# fontsize of title is 12.0? 
print ax.title.get_fontsize()

12.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title):

> Set one of the three available axes titles. The available titles are
>   positioned above the axes in the center, flush with the left edge, and
>   flush with the right edge.

So, there are 3 different titles. When you execute `dir(ax)` you can notice there `'_left_title'` and `'_right_title'`. So:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('test_title', loc='left', fontsize=30)
print ax._left_title.get_fontsize()

30.0
```